# Assign a style if php array containts value

Tags: php, css, json, styles, themoviedb-api

Hi Im using tmdb api and fetching a actors movies list var json. the code works how I want it to apart from I am trying to style the movie thumbnail differently to the rest if the film is a horror.

```
$tmdb = $_GET['tmdb'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/".$tmdb."?api_key=#######");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
$person = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$actor= json_decode($person, true); // Decode the results into an array
$name = $actor['name'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?&with_cast=".$tmdb."&vote_count.gte=5&sort_by=release_date.desc&api_key=#######");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
$personCredits = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$credits= json_decode($personCredits, true); // Decode the results into an array

$counter4 = 0;
$counter5 = 0;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($credits);
echo "</pre>";

$page=1;
echo "<div style='width:800px;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;ktop:1100px;left:75'>";

while ( $page <= $credits['total_pages'] ) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?&with_cast=".$tmdb."&vote_count.gte=5&sort_by=release_date.desc&page=".$page."&api_key=#######");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    $personCredits = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $credits= json_decode($personCredits, true); // Decode the results into an array

    $resultsCount4=(count($credits['results']))-1;
    while ( $counter4 <= $resultsCount4 ) {

        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP PLEASE>>>>>
        if($credits['results'][$counter4]['genre_ids'] == 27) {
            $style="horror"; 
        } else { $style="round"; }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        echo "<div style='width:200;height:260;float:left;text-overflow:ellipsis    white-space: nowrap; 
                        width: 14em; 
                        overflow: hidden;
                        '><center><div class='".$style."'><a href=\"/?id=moviepage.php&ttno=".$credits['results'][$counter4]['id']."\"><img width=\"154\" height=\"231\"onerror=\"this.src='nocover.png'\" src='http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/".$credits['results'][$counter4]['poster_path']."'></div><br>".$credits['results'][$counter4]['title']."<br>".$credits['results'][$counter4]['release_date']."</center></a></div>";
        $counter4++;
    }
    $page++;
    $counter4=0;
}
```

the Json array looks like

```
    Array
      (
        [page] => 1
   [results] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [poster_path] => /ceVMgY3TzLrfEpaMfaOnPDYnfqA.jpg
                [adult] => 
                [overview] => John Wick is forced out of retirement by a former associate looking to seize control of a shadowy international assassinsâ€™ guild Bound by a blood oath to aid him, Wick travels to Rome and does battle against some of the worldâ€™s most dangerous killers.

                [release_date] => 2017-02-10
                [genre_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 28
                    )

                [id] => 324552
                [original_title] => John Wick: Chapter Two
                [original_language] => en
                [title] => John Wick: Chapter Two
                [backdrop_path] => /6TPIMjoyRKCKhCGeGigP99qQTWw.jpg
                [popularity] => 1.714191
                [vote_count] => 7
                [video] => 
                [vote_average] => 9.57
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [poster_path] => /l9Eu1e3qNvFSvi66WtHFBoHIgeT.jpg
                [adult] => 
                [overview] => A defense attorney works to get his teenage client acquitted of murdering his wealthy father.
                [release_date] => 2016-06-10
                [genre_ids] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 18
                        [1] => 53
                    )

                [id] => 331583
                [original_title] => The Whole Truth
                [original_language] => en
                [title] => The Whole Truth
                [backdrop_path] => /1pwF12CCtUSmCifDGhZHohp5qYu.jpg
                [popularity] => 1.875005
                [vote_count] => 6
                [video] => 
                [vote_average] => 6.67
            )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Learn to use `foreach` so you don't have to keep repeating `$credits['results'][$counter4]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`genre_ids` is an array (notice that the name is plural, and "The Whole Truth" is in two genres), not a number, so

```
if($credits['results'][$counter4]['genre_ids'] == 27)
```

won't work. Use `in_array()`

```
if (in_array(27, $credits['results'][$counter4]['genre_ids'])
```